# How to count how many maximum numbers there are among inputted in one line values?

Tags: python, count, max

I've got 4 integer inputs in one line separated by a space, and I have to output the largest of them and how many largest integers there are, also in one line and separated by a space. The first request can be easily done with a `max` function, however I can't figure out how to do the second one. Example:

Input: `6 4 -3 6`

Output: `6 2`

And this is code I've written so far:

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, input().split())
max = max(a,b,c,d)
print(max, )
```

How can I count the amount of largest integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
x = "6 4 -3 6"
l = list(map(int, x.split()))
print(max(l), l.count(max(l)))
```

Where `x` is the string that you got from the call to `input()`.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but You showed me that there is a `count` function, as it turns out. So thank You for that!